# Excel XLookup check if date is between two values in a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

This is the same question as in "`XLOOKUP()` with multiple criteria and date between two dates" I found on this forum, but that question wasn't solved, so here is my attempt.

I have a (named) table with a column named "**Datum**", now I want to check the value of this field in a table that looks like the table in the image:

[image]

For this I use the `XLOOKUP()` formula. I have the following syntax:

```
=@XLOOKUP(1;[@Datum]>=V$3:V$8*[@Datum]<W$3:W$8;U$2:$U$8)
```

V3:V6 is the **from** column in the image
W3:W8 is the **till** column in the image

When the condition is met, it should return the value from the sprint column.

I cannot get it to work though. Any suggestions?

Comment: `FILTER` or `SUMIFS` is likely more appropriate here.

Comment: The `BOOLEAN` Logic needs to be within `Brackets` Look the way I have posted in answers! But If you want to return multiple results then `FILTER()` would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use <kbd>XLOOKUP()</kbd> function as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>Z2</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(Y2>=$V$2:$V$7)*(Y2<=$W$2:$W$7),$U$2:$U$7)
```

---

In Dutch Version it remains same, only the separators are different:

```
=XLOOKUP(1;(Y2>=$V$2:$V$7)*(Y2<=$W$2:$W$7);$U$2:$U$7)
```

---

With <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=FILTER($U$2:$U$7,(Y2>=$V$2:$V$7)*(Y2<=$W$2:$W$7),0)
```

---

**Caveat:** I am not sure whether you want the sum of those values between two dates or not if so, then <kbd>XLOOKUP()</kbd> is not the right function here, then you would need to use either <kbd>SUM()</kbd> or <kbd>SUMPRODUCT()</kbd>.

---

Comment: Very usefull information. I have never worked or seen the filter function, so that is also good to know. Your answer helped me best solving my issue. I simplefied my question, but as said, your answer helped me solve my problem. Thank you. The problem in my case was indeed not using the brackets. I totally overlooked that.

Comment: Glad to know that!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `XLOOKUP`like this - but

`=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A4*(B2:B4<=Datum)*(C2:C4>=Datum))`

will work
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your context, where there are *no days skipped between the earliest* from *date and the latest* till *date* you could also go retro and avoid any boolean tests:
[image: Screenshot illustrating INDEX/MATCH approach]

Comment: Or, also without boolean tests `=XLOOKUP(E2:E5,B2:B7,A2:A7,,-1)`